# Finding superimpose level in percentage of two same circles

Tags: java

I have to two circles (circle-1, circle-2) with centers of x1,y1 and x2,y2 subsequently, having same size.

Now i want to calculate percentage of superimpose of cir2 on cir1 (in percentage)
(ex) If cir2 fully covers cir1 and then superimpose = 100%
if half superimpose is done the score will ve 50%, if not superimpose at all = 0%.

How to do this.....?

Any Guide....

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Finding little difficult to understand.  Is any other way to calculate (ex) using distance between to points formula distance = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)); and so one....

Comment: Mean to say through Distance formula can we convert into some percentage value

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks Andy. 
I got an idea from the link you provide. 
Though the idea is not the best, but it solves the purpose..

double radius = 40.0;
int x1 =100;    //first Circle X value
int y1 = 100;   //first Circle Y value
int x2 = 100;   //second Circle X value
int y2 = 100;  //second Circle Y value

double iDist = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
double per = (100.0-(iDist/radius)*100);    //get the value in %
System.out.println("Distance: "+iDist + "("+per+"%)");


OUTPUT:

if values are (100,100) and (100,100) then o/p : 100%
if values are (100,100) and (120,100) then o/p : 50%
if values are (100,100) and (140,100) then o/p : 0%
if values are (100,100) and (600,600) then o/p : percentage in negative value (ex) - 973%


All the best....!
```